# Static resources in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Does Xamarin.iOS offer an equivalent to a the `ResourceDictionary` in Windows or `Resources` in Android?

Something that would enable you to define your application's colors and be able to use them in the designer without repeating the RGB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to do it programmatically using the appearance api.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_the_appearance_api/